# s3 put json file access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am using linux s3cmd to upload files to AWS S3.  I can upload a zip file successfully and this has been working for months now, no problems.  I now need to also upload a json file.  When I try to upload the json file to the same bucket, I get S3 error: Access Denied.  I can't figure out why, please help.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

s3cmd --mime-type=application/zip put myfile.zip s3://mybucket
SUCCESS

s3cmd --mime-type=application/json put myfile.json s3://mybucket
ERROR: S3 error: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 0):

These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

The `aws s3 cp` command will try to automatically guess the mime type, so you might not need to specify it as in your example.

If your heart is set on figuring out why `s3cmd` doesn't work, try opening up permissions (eg allow `s3:*`) to see if this fixes things, then narrow-down the list of permitted API calls to figure out which one `s3cmd` is calling.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had tried changing the allow action to all ("*") already with no change.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [Minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) Using *mc cp* command this can be done.

```
$ mc cp myfile.json s3alias/mybucket
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug with s3cmd, simple update solved the problem.